# Key error when selecting a column in pandas dataframe after read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV file and running into error when trying to print any column. Printing the whole dataset works but not a particular column. I see that there are no spaces in the column names.

```
df_all = pd.read_csv('feb_25.csv')
print(df_cpu.columns.tolist())
df_cpu.head(5)
```

['datetimestamp', 'cpu_usage_p', 'mth_ave_cpu_usage_p', 'mth_max_cpu_usage_p']

Out[298]:

```
   datetimestamp    cpu_usage_p mth_ave_cpu_usage_p mth_max_cpu_usage_p
0   2016-10-03 05:08:00 59.1    51.68   99.87
1   2017-01-14 02:01:00 69.31   59.36   100
2   2016-12-02 14:00:00 73.78   84.51   100
3   2017-01-16 10:01:00 36.19   56.79   100
4   2017-01-06 00:00:00 69.2    42.00   100


>>>df_cpu[df_cpu.cpu_usage_p]<<<


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-299-4b0ea47da1c6> in <module>()
----> 1 df_cpu[df_cpu.cpu_usage_p]

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2051         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2052             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2053             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2054         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2055             return self._getitem_frame(key)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2095             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2096         else:
-> 2097             indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2098             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2099 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1228                 mask = check == -1
   1229                 if mask.any():
-> 1230                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1231 
   1232                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['59.1' '69.31' '73.78' ..., '75.86' '81.7' '72.07'] not in index"
```

Comment: You should take a look at the Indexing section of the docs, what you attempted looks rather confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df_cpu['cpu_usage_p']`

df_cpu.cpu_usage_p refers to a specific column and when passed to df_cpu data frame as a `Key`, of course it is not found.